# Negative SDR result for evaluating audio source separation

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning, signals, signal-processing

I'm trying to use [eval_mus_track](https://sigsep.github.io/sigsep-mus-eval/#museval.eval_mus_track) function of the [museval](https://pypi.org/project/museval/) package to evaluate my audio source separation model. The model I'm evaluating was trained to predict vocals and the results are similar to the actual vocals but the evaluation metrics such as SDR are negative.

Below is my function for generating the metrics:

```
def estimate_and_evaluate(track):

    #track.audio is stereo therefore we predict each channel separately
    vocals_predicted_channel_1, acompaniment_predicted_channel_1, _ = model_5.predict(np.squeeze(track.audio[:, 0]))
    vocals_predicted_channel_2, acompaniment_predicted_channel_2, _  = model_5.predict(np.squeeze(track.audio[:, 1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            )


    vocals = np.squeeze(np.array([vocals_predicted_channel_1.wav_file, vocals_predicted_channel_2.wav_file])).T
    accompaniment = np.squeeze(np.array([acompaniment_predicted_channel_1.wav_file, acompaniment_predicted_channel_2.wav_file])).T
    estimates = {
        'vocals': vocals,
        'accompaniment': accompaniment
    }

    scores = museval.eval_mus_track(track, estimates)
    print(scores)
```

The metric values I get are:

```
vocals          ==> SDR:  -3.776  SIR:   4.621  ISR:  -0.005  SAR: -30.538  
accompaniment   ==> SDR:  -0.590  SIR:   1.704  ISR:  -0.006  SAR: -16.613
```

The above result doesn't make sense because first of all, accompaniment prediction is pure noise as this model was trained for vocals but it gets a higher SDR. The second reason is the predicted vocals have a very similar graph to the actual ones but still gets a negative SDR value!
In the following graphs, the top one is the actual sound and the bottom one is the predicted source:

Channel 1:
[image: actual vocals channel 1]
[image: predicted vocals channel 1]

Channel 2:
[image: actual vocals channel 2]
[image: predicted vocals channel 2]
I tried to shift the predicted vocals as mentioned [here](https://github.com/craffel/mir_eval/issues/316#issuecomment-626815638) but the result got worse.

Any idea what's causing this issue?

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RqCViuJvUPPGmBHa5JBa0n3Y2jgnX5Qo/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the actual vocals stereo numpy array
and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16h12milk56JuWDKEQTc_XymgIPOi-gjv/view?usp=sharing) one to the predicted stereo vocals numpy array. you can load and manipulate them by using `np.load`
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The signal to distortion ratio is actually the logarithm of a ratio. See equation (12) of this article:
https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00630985/PDF/vincent_SigPro11.pdf

So, a SDR of 0 means that the signal is equal to the distortion. An SDR value of less than 0 means that there is more distortion than signal. If the audio doesn't sound like there is more distortion than signal, the cause is often sample alignment problems.

When you look at equation (12), you can see that the calculation depends strongly on preserving the exact sample alignment of the predicted a ground-truth audio. It can be difficult to tell from plots of the waveform or even listening if the samples are misaligned. But, a zoomed-in plot where you can see each individual sample could help you make sure that the ground truth and predicted samples are exactly lined up. If it is shifted by even a single sample, the SDR calculation will not reflect the actual SDR.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How would I be able to fix the mismatch? I read about something like cross correlation but not sure how to use it

Comment: In some applications, you could search for the amount of samples to shift one of the signals so that the cross-correlation between the signals is maximized. But, for a source separation model, you should be able to train it to output correctly-aligned audio so that you don't have to fix the mismatch. If you are using a loss function that doesn't care about sample alignment, consider adding an MAE term in the time domain. If you are happy with the model outputs, perhaps simply avoiding metrics that depend on sample alignment is best. But focus on diagnosing the cause before applying any fixes.

Comment: The loss function I’m using is actually calculates the absolute different between each pixel of spectrograms so it should take care of sample allignment. The only reason of the mistmatch I can think of is the padding I add to the end of input before processing it. But still I’m not sure what’s causing it

Comment: If you are using the full complex spectrogram in your loss function, your model should be able to learn to predict sample-aligned outputs. But, if you are using a magnitude or power spectrogram and using the noisy phase, or approximating the phase with Griffin-Lim or other algorithms, then that could be the source of the issue since the phase will not be getting predicted accurately. Padding the input is okay, just make sure that you are using the padded version as input to your metrics as well.